# Neatest way to access my data source (Serial port) from an NSTableViewDataSource in Swift (OSX)?

Tags: iphone, macos, swift, serial-port

I have an NSTableView in my simple app and a separate class SettingsTableSourceDelegate that inherits from NSTableViewDataSource and NSTableViewDelegate to handle populating and processing the table. Essentially the table is going to be populated from values received from a microcontroller, the specifics of aren't important, but what I want to know is a more general question of structure.

What is the best way, other than (if possible) singletons or storing my serial port instance in the app delegate, to access my serial port instance from my SettingsTableSourceDelegate class? Giving consideration to the fact that I don't want to be constantly closing and opening the port, and that the NSTableView isn't the only thing going to be using the port (though not at the same time).

I ideally would want the table to initially pull its values from the microcontroller over serial, then further manipulations done to the table are performed on a copy in memory, and only sent back when a Save button is clicked.

Many thanks for your time, I'm not very hot on design patterns and Swift/OSX programming is very new to me so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should start a separate thread for the serial port. Assuming you just display the data coming from the controller it's quite save to alter the table data source. If you are going to alter the count you need to be a bit more careful. Adding will just delay but deleting will eventually cause the table view to access already deleted entries.